# Make wrapped div go to end

Tags: css, flexbox

When a flex item wraps to a new line it goes to the start of the line but I want it to behave like `space-between`.

For instance this code:

```css
.container{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item{
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">&lt; This is a long sentence that makes next item wrap</div>
  <div class="item">This is small &gt;</div>
</div>
```

How can I make it look like this:

[image]

Comment: How about using css grid instead of flexbox ? would you consider that ?

Comment: yes css grid is fine

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but if you want your first div to stay where it is, and you want your second div to move to the end of the box, what you can do is simply add in a middle div and set its visibility to hidden. That way there is something that will fill up that space and push your "this is small" div to the edge of the container. I made the following modifications to your code and this seems to create the effect you're looking for.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item1">&lt; This is a long sentence that makes next item wrap</div>
  <div class="item item2">This is medium</div>
  <div class="item item3">This is small &gt;</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item{
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.item2 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It could also be done by setting justify-content in the container to flex-end and and giving the first item its own class that has the margin-right property set to auto.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the `space-between` behavior and achieve your desired result, what we could do is target only the last item, which is the one you want to be positioned on the right and just modify the `margin`.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item1">&lt; This is a long sentence that makes next item wrap</div>
  <div class="item item2">This is medium</div>
  <div class="item item3">This is small &gt;</div>
</div>

.container{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item{
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Setting `margin-left` to `auto`

```
.item:last-child {
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the job of float (yes float ...)

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow:auto;
}

.item {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.item:last-child {
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">&lt; This is a long sentence that makes next item wrap</div>
  <div class="item">This is small &gt;</div>
</div>
```